# Get geofence names by list of coordinates

Tags: python, geolocation, coordinates, gis, polygon

I have a task to receive names of highways according to the list of coordinates of cars. Cars drive all over the world. Every day I get a list of about 800 thousand new coordinates.

I see two solutions:

1. Using third party API servers for reverse geocoding. Obvious problems:

- google is too expensive
- nominatim from OSM has a limit of 1 request per second. It is not possible to use your own nominate instance

2. Get the coordinates of all highways in the world as polygonal geofences to then use mpltPath.Path to count the number of occurrences of coordinates in the geofence. It works fast, I checked. Problems:

- I don't have a single standardized source of highway geofences from all over the world.

How would you solve this problem?
What are fast and inexpensive API other than google and osm?
Where can I get geofences for all highways in the world?

Comment: what have you tried so far and where is the code ?

Comment: OpenStreetMap and PostGIS nearest line will probably be things to google

Comment: I tried both described solutions. They work, there are no problems with the code, that's why I didn't put it here. The problem is in the approach to the solution.